# Roku:VAST tag implement

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am working on roku app using scene graph component, i want to implement VAST tag for ad in roku app using scene graph. How to implement VAST tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing support for video advertising in Roku apps is done through the [Roku Advertising Framework](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Roku+Advertising+Framework). That framework supports various versions of the VAST standard.